# Read an html table via URL with R

Tags: html, r

I'm trying to add this data https://datahub.io/core/country-list/r/0.html to R as a df, but can't find a function to read a table from html file.
(the link to the git post about the data https://datahub.io/core/country-list#readme)

read_csv and read.table doesn't work.

I want to add this data to my df and use it in a project. Will appreciate your help!

read_csv and read.table doesn't work. I also tried XML package but got an error:

```
readHTMLTable("http://datahub.io/core/country-list/r/0.html", header = c(Country_Name, Code))

Error: failed to load external entity "http://datahub.io/core/country-list/r/0.html"
```

The same error I got using htmlParse

I want to add this data to my df and use it in a project. Will appreciate your help!

Comment: Page loads it as a csv file via javascript - you can access it directly: `"https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/country-list/data_csv/data/d7c9d7cfb42cb69f4422dec222dbbaa8/data_csv.csv" |> read.csv()`

Comment: Thank you! This helped. How did you generate the link?

Comment: Just looked at the network requests made by the page.